# CMFCMenuBar showing wrong tooltips

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have a SDI project with Feature Pack enabled.
The program has a Menu Bar (**CMFCMenuBar**) and four Tool Bars(**CMFCToolBar**).

Toolbars works correctly: I assigned to the TB's buttons the ID of equivalent menu items and I see TB images on menu voices.

Now, when I hover on some menu voices (always the same) I got some random tooltips text, I say random because I searched my project and I don't have those two strings written in any part of my solution, for example:

[image: Picture error 1]
[image: Picture error 2]
[image: Picture Error 3]

I have recently done some manual modification in resource.h file scrumbling some ids... that might be a problem?

Also, I tried to fix the problem by telling Menu to not show tooltips:

```
dwStile = m_wndMenuBar.GetPaneStyle() | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC/* | CBRS_TOOLTIPS*/ | CBRS_FLYBY;
m_wndMenuBar.SetPaneStyle(dwStile);
```

but, as you can see in the images above, I got no results at all.

Any idea where I can look for the error?

Comment: Check your ID values in resource.h

Comment: @VuVirt What exactly should I look for?

Comment: Overlapping ID values for instance

Comment: All the IDs are unque, already checked.

Comment: Please check my answer, if you have any suggestions.

Comment: The resource ID values must be higher than 1000.

Comment: Are you sure? When you create a new project from models there are a couple of IDs that are below 1000, now I have 148 of them: bitmaps, icons, dialogs and the mainframe.

Comment: Moreover: why, if I add a String Table the IDs starts from 1 by default?

Comment: I meant the command IDs

Comment: The rule is the command IDs should be greater than WM_USER: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Well, I'm getting confused. Which is the right documentation to refer? isn't this the new definitive guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/cpp/windows/overview-of-windows-programming-in-cpp

Comment: I've always used MSDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I found that the "random strings" where the second part (after \n) of strings stored in the resources of a DLL which my program use. While the dll dialogs have IDs in range [2000, 2500], the 3 strings have id: 1, 2, 3.

I don't remember where I read that such low ids might be dangerous so I changed it manually to 3000, 3001 and 3002 and this fixed the problem.

Even if this worked, I would like to know why, so feel free to edit the answer and add the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the Resource IDE you can specify what the popup text is:

[image: The Prompt and Tooltip Text]

In the above example I used:

> Open dialogue to manage and modify talk assignments and various appointments\nManage Talk Assignments

Notice the use of **\n**? That is what splits the two text string components up. Thus, in the final application:

[image: Example]

So you should be able to specify all of your text correctly in the IDE editor.

Comment: It's not this. I have, for example, the voice "Proiezione \ Configura" which has unique id and the prompt set to "Apre la finestra di configurazione della proiezione\nConfigura Proiezione" and the result is the same: "Conferma Generazione".

Comment: Please check my answer if you wish.